# How can I use arrays in unix shell?

Tags: shell, loops, unix

I use code in !/bin/sh like this:

```
LIST1="mazda toyota honda"
LIST2="2009 2006 2010"

for m in $LIST1
do
 echo $m
done
```

As you can see this currently prints out only the make of the car.
How can I include the year to each "echo" based on the same positions so that I get results like:

mazda 2009

toyota 2006

honda 2010

?

Comment: When you are at the point of needing arrays in shell, shouldn't you be considering Python instead?

Comment: It would help if you said which shell you're using.

Comment: He said he is using sh shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, bash does have arrays, see `man bash`. The generic posix shell does not.

The shell is not precisely a macro processor, however, and so any metaprogramming must be processed by an `eval` or, in bash, with the `${!variable}` syntax. That is, in a macro processor like nroff you can easily fake up arrays by making variables called a1, a2, a3, a4, etc.

You can do that in the posix shell but requires a lot of eval's or the equivalent like `$(($a))`.

```
$ i=1 j=2; eval a$i=12 a$j=34
$ for i in 1 2; do echo $((a$i)); done
12
34
$
```

And for a bash-specific example...

```
$ a=(56 78)
$ echo ${a[0]}
56
$ echo ${a[1]}
78
$
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming bash

```
array1=(mazda toyota honda)
array2=(2009 2006 2010)

for index in ${!array1[*]}
do
    printf "%s %s\n" ${array1[$index]} ${array2[$index]}
done
```

Comment: in my shell it has to be array1="mazda toyota honda" otherwise I get a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays but just to be different here's a method that doesn't need them:

```
LIST1="mazda toyota honda"
LIST2="2009 2006 2010"

paste -d' ' <(echo $LIST1 | tr ' ' '\n') <(echo $LIST2 | tr ' ' '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $IFS var to fake arrays for example (works with any posix compilant shell):

```
    hosts=mingw:bsd:linux:osx # for example you have the variable with all aviable hosts
    # the advantage between other methods is that you have still one element and all contens get adressed through this 
    old_ifs=$IFS #save the old $IFS
    IFS=: # say sh to seperate all commands by : 
    for var in $hosts ; do
     # now we can use every element of $var
     IFS=$old_ifs
     echo $var
    done
    IFS=$Old_ifs
```

If you wrap this in a function you can use them like a real array

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, please include why/how your answer solves the problem.